# How to reconnect to socket.io namespace after disconnect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I connect to a namespace like

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/random');
```

then i disconnect like this

```
 socket.disconnect();
```

my question is how do I reconnect to the 'random' namespace using the socket again?
I tried using

```
 socket.socket.connect('http://localhost:3000/random');
```

not working

Comment: Try doing `socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/random');` again.

Comment: ^didn't work, I think socket.io should improve its dcumentation since so many are using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect using

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/random');
```

Cleanly disconnect using

```
 socket.socket.disconnect();
```

Reconnect using

```
 socket.socket.reconnect();
```